# Trying to make a very simple speech recognition windows form project

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, speech-recognition

I followed a very basic tutorial (forgot the link) and it all seems straightforward, but I don't seem to be getting the output I want. Here is my main form class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Speech.Recognition;

namespace OralNotes.Alpha
{
public partial class MainForm : Form
{
    private SpeechRecognitionEngine recognitionEngine;

    public MainForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        recognitionEngine = new SpeechRecognitionEngine();
        recognitionEngine.SetInputToDefaultAudioDevice();
        recognitionEngine.SpeechRecognized += (s, args) =>
          {
              foreach (RecognizedWordUnit word in args.Result.Words)
              {
                  if (word.Confidence > 0.8f)
                      txtNotes.Text += word.Text + " ";

              }
              txtNotes.Text += Environment.NewLine;
          };
        recognitionEngine.LoadGrammar(new DictationGrammar());
    }

    private void btnStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        recognitionEngine.RecognizeAsync();
    }

    private void btnStop_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        recognitionEngine.RecognizeAsyncStop();
    }
}
}
```

And you probably don't need this, but here it is anyway:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace OralNotes.Alpha
{
static class Program
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The main entry point for the application.
    /// </summary>
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.Run(new MainForm());
    }
}
}
```

I click start and talk, and nothing happens.

***UPDATE****

ok so this is working, if I adjust this line

```
if (word.Confidence > 0.8f)
```

to a lower number I get a word or two in. Not transcribing sentences or anything, is there a way to make this have better recognition?

Comment: When you say you click start do you mean you run the application and the form does not show?

Comment: Sorry, There is a button "Start" that I click is supposed to start the listening I guess. The form loads fine.

Comment: Would be beneficial to post that code since that is what starts the routine.

Comment: This is ALL the code. It is just a single form visual studio winform application.

Comment: ok, it sounds like you have not defined an onclick event handler for your button.  Move the speech code into its own method.  Then add an onClick handler that calls that method.  Post back if you need help with that.

Comment: Is that not the btnStart_Click stuff I have?

Comment: Loading an empty grammar isn't going to help it recognize any words.

Comment: Hans, check my update. How do I load in dictionaries of words and stuff?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the engine that you are using returns a confidence value on every word it hears.

I suspect that the confidence values range from 0-1. Which means that if you lower the value from 0.8 you are making the engine more tolerant to words. Maybe it is the quality of your mic?